# TypeError: dispatch is not a function in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dispatch

I am new to React and was trying to build an app that shows the contacts that you input. While everything seems to be fine, the browser is throwing me this error every time I try to add a new contact.

[image]

Here is my `Contacts.js`

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";

import { Container, ListGroup, ListGroupItem, Spinner } from "reactstrap";
import Contact from "../components/Contact";
import { MdAdd } from "react-icons/md";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { ContactContext } from "../context/Context";
import { CONTACT_TO_UPDATE } from "../context/action.types";

const Contacts = () => {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(ContactContext);

  // destructuring contacts and isLoading from state
  const { contacts, isLoading } = state;

  // history hooks from react router dom to get history
  const history = useHistory();

  // handle fab icon button click
  // will set in state of the contact to update and send it to the contact/add route
  const AddContact = () => {
    //TODO: use dispatch to send user to add contact screen
    dispatch({                             //THE ERROR IS HERE!
      type: CONTACT_TO_UPDATE,
      payload: null,
      key: null
    });
    history.push("/contact/add");
  };

  // return loading spinner
  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <div className="Center">
        <Spinner color="primary" />
        <div className="text-primary">Loading...</div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Container className="mt-4">
      {/* TODO: Loop through FIREBASE objects  */}
      {contacts.length === 0 && !isLoading ? (
        <div className="Center text-large text-primary">
          NO Contacts found in firebase
        </div>
      ) : (
        <ListGroup>
          {Object.entries(contacts).map(([key, value]) => (
            <ListGroupItem key={key}>
              <Contact contact={value} contactKey={key} />
            </ListGroupItem>
          ))}
        </ListGroup>
      )}
      <MdAdd className="fab icon " onClick={AddContact} />
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Contacts;
```

It would be really helpful if the answer is a bit beginner-friendly.

Comment: can you show the code for `ContactContext`

Comment: @Jagrati, ```import { createContext } from "react";

export const ContactContext = createContext();```

Comment: can you add it in your question.. the file `ContactContext ` and sample code.

Comment: You are not passing any value to your `createContext `, so it won't have a dispatch method

Comment: But, according to the docs(https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#api), a value is only required when a component does not have a matching Provider above it

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: make sure your importing from 'react-redux' and not 'react'